# emit a local event with socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io on the server side (and client).

What I want to do is trigger an event on disconnect. But it doesn't seem to get picked up locally.

In the node server I have:

```
sock.on('chat:leave', function(user){
     //delete user from chat room list
});

sock.on('disconnect', function(){
    var user = sock.user;
    sock.emit('chat:leave', user);
});
```

This however is not working -- the disconnect is firing when I close the browser window, but the `chat:leave` emitted from the `disconnect` callback is not getting picked up by the `sock.on('chat:leave')` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to rewrite your code (AFAIK, what you're trying to do isn't possible):

```
var userLeft = function(user) {
  // delete user from chat room list
};
sock.on('chat:leave', userLeft);
sock.on('disconnect', function() {
  userLeft(sock.user);
});
```

Comment: That's  how I got it working. Just wondered if it would listen for local emissions.